# differences between mapi and ews?

Tags: c++, exchangewebservices, mapi

all, I'm new to Exchange programming and now I wonder what the exact differences between MAPI and EWS if I wanna create a mail client(using C++) to communicate with Exchange. Despite the versions they supported, which one is more efficient? And which is more easier to develop with?(I've heard that EWS is easier, but not sure about that) I've found everywhere and got nothing about the efficiency comparison. Please someone help me, or show me some place I can look into and find out that myself.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, I've googled for a long time, but it seems there is not much helpful information I need, or maybe I didn't google it the right way, so I can here and ask for help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a message board.

Answer (score 0):

These resources might be of use to you:

- [Development technologies for earlier versions of Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877032%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx): Talks about how MAPI is "de-emphasized but still supported in Exchange 2013". EWS and/or the EWS Managed API are the current recommended development technologies.
- [Messaging API evaluation criteria](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579299%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

The EWS Managed API is just a wrapper for EWS and is quite simple to get started with using C#, if you want to move to C#. Otherwise you can use EWS and C++ to create your SOAP calls. My personal belief is that you'd save time by using the EWS Managed API, even though you'd have to learn the diffs between C++ and C# - but maybe that's not an option. If it's not an option, I'd recommend EWS over MAPI. To give you an idea of how easy it is to work with the EWS Managed API, take a look at [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Mimi, that's very kind of you.